# How to create an indicator column of the first occurrence of a variable of groupby ID sorted by date?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have some hospital visit healthcare data in a dataframe of the form:

| CLIENT_ID | DATE_ENCOUNTER | DATE_COUNSELLING | COUNSELLING_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54950 | 2017-11-24 | NaN | 0 |
| 54950 | 2018-01-19 | NaN | 0 |
| 54950 | 2018-03-13 | NaN | 0 |
| 54950 | 2018-05-11 | 2018-04-30 | 1 |
| 54950 | 2018-12-17 | 2018-06-25 | 3 |
| 67777 | 2015-09-01 | NaN | 0 |
| 67777 | 2015-12-01 | NaN | 0 |
| 67777 | 2016-02-28 | 2016-02-28 | 1 |
| 70000 | 2019-06-07 | 2019-06-07 | 1 |
| 70000 | 2019-08-09 | 2019-06-07 | 1 |

I want to create a column `COUNSELLING_STARTED` which indicates whether a client `CLIENT_ID` has started counselling, but only the first time. i.e. The first occurence when `COUNSELLING_COUNT == 1` for each `CLIENT_ID` which should result in the dataframe below:

| CLIENT_ID | DATE_ENCOUNTER | DATE_COUNSELLING | COUNSELLING_COUNT | COUNSELLING_STARTED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54950 | 2017-11-24 | NaN | 0 | 0 |
| 54950 | 2018-01-19 | NaN | 0 | 0 |
| 54950 | 2018-03-13 | NaN | 0 | 0 |
| 54950 | 2018-05-11 | 2018-04-30 | 1 | 1 |
| 54950 | 2018-12-17 | 2018-06-25 | 3 | 0 |
| 67777 | 2015-09-01 | NaN | 0 | 0 |
| 67777 | 2015-12-01 | NaN | 0 | 0 |
| 67777 | 2016-02-28 | 2016-02-28 | 1 | 1 |
| 70000 | 2019-06-07 | 2019-06-07 | 1 | 1 |
| 70000 | 2019-08-09 | 2019-06-07 | 1 | 0 |

below is the code to generate the dataframe:

```
data = {'CLIENT_ID':[54950,54950,54950,54950,54950,67777,67777,67777,70000,70000],
'DATE_ENCOUNTER':['2017-11-24','2018-01-19','2018-03-13','2018-05-11','2018-12-17','2015-09-01','2015-12-01','2016-02-28','2019-06-07','2019-08-09'],
'DATE_COUNSELLING':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'2018-04-30','2018-06-25',np.nan,np.nan,'2016-02-28','2019-06-07','2019-06-07'],
'COUNSELLING_COUNT':[0,0,0,1,3,0,0,1,1,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Why is 67777 has no COUNSELLING_STARTED?

Answer (score 1):

### Update

In my original answer, I had missed the fact that if someone has no counseling dates, my method would assign a `1` to their first entry.  Here are two quick ways to fix that.

One option is to explicitly drop those rows with NA before you do the groupby i describe:

```
dropped = df[~df['DATE_COUNSELLING'].isna()]
df.loc[:, 'COUNSELLING_STARTED'] = 0
df.loc[dropped['DATE_COUNSELLING'].isna().groupby(dropped['CLIENT_ID']).idxmin(), 'COUNSELLING_STARTED'] = 1
# note that `dropped` is used inside the brackets in the last line
```

Second option is to simply do exactly what I had before, but then overwrite the erroneous entries (i.e., where the counseling is NA):

```
df.loc[:, 'COUNSELLING_STARTED'] = 0
df.loc[df['DATE_COUNSELLING'].isna().groupby(df['CLIENT_ID']).idxmin(), 'COUNSELLING_STARTED'] = 1
df.loc[df['DATE_COUNSELLING'].isna(), 'COUNSELLING_STARTED'] = 0
# last line catches people with no counseling
```

*This was my original answer*:

```
df.loc[:, 'COUNSELLING_STARTED'] = 0
df.loc[df['DATE_COUNSELLING'].isna().groupby(df['CLIENT_ID']).idxmin(), 'COUNSELLING_STARTED'] = 1
```

---

#### Explanation (using my first approach):

Find where the counseling dates are `nan`; then groupby the client IDs and find the index of the minimum (which will be the first entry):

```
>>> dropped['DATE_COUNSELLING'].isna().groupby(dropped['CLIENT_ID']).idxmin()
CLIENT_ID
54950    3
67777    7
70000    8
Name: DATE_COUNSELLING, dtype: int64
```

You are using these indices to choose where to write `1` in the new column.  And even though `dropped` does not have any NA values, we still use `.isna()` in the groupby in order to get a value that we can take a `min` on (instead of a string).  You could also do something like `.astype(bool)`.

The final `df` is then:

```
   CLIENT_ID DATE_ENCOUNTER  ... COUNSELLING_COUNT  COUNSELLING_STARTED
0      54950     2017-11-24  ...                 0                    0
1      54950     2018-01-19  ...                 0                    0
2      54950     2018-03-13  ...                 0                    0
3      54950     2018-05-11  ...                 1                    1
4      54950     2018-12-17  ...                 3                    0
5      67777     2015-09-01  ...                 0                    0
6      67777     2015-12-01  ...                 0                    0
7      67777     2016-02-28  ...                 1                    1
8      70000     2019-06-07  ...                 1                    1
9      70000     2019-08-09  ...                 1                    0

[10 rows x 5 columns]
```

If you wanted to instead explicitly select the earliest counseling date (rather than the first non-NA value), you could instead use this as your indexer:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(dropped['DATE_COUNSELLING']).groupby(dropped['CLIENT_ID']).idxmin()
CLIENT_ID
54950    3
67777    7
70000    8
Name: DATE_COUNSELLING, dtype: int64
```

Which gives the same result here since the dates are sorted for each client (i.e. the earliest observed date is the first non-NA value).

Comment: 1st answer is incorrect: if there is only one entry for CLIENT_ID with NaN entry then 1 is indicated even though it's not true @Tom

Comment: @Mazil_tov998 ah good catch!  I updated my answer, hopefully it is working now